# Why my super simple ASP.NET Web API (mvc4)+Entity Framework 5 doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I spent days to know the problems of my work, but no luck.

1. I created new MVC4 Web API project.
2. Add EF5 with my database (Project>Add>ADO.NET Entity Data Model>Create from database which is in Azure SQL).
3. Add two tables to edmx as below. And two *.tt files generate entities and model classes successfully.

[image]

**I can see the breakpoint(result) gives query result normally.**
But json gives abnormal stream without error message. (ie, `http://localhost:41813/api/sheet/157` returns "157" which cannot download. in general, "157.json" is downloaded)

[image]

I copied properties in results to my handmade POCO-style class and it works.

What is my problem? I cannot use generated model classes to send data through Json.
I hardly find out problem because no error message and no debug step available after the result breakpoint.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the json serialization. Can you try xml serialization (just add "Accept: application/xml" in request headers from the client) and see if you can download the data?

Comment: @Sando // applicatin/xml cannot solve. thanks for your comment. Below answer gives me the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the serialization fails are yours *Navigation Properties* - while the serializer is trying to walk the object graph they result in circular dependencies.

For your simple sample to work you have few ways around it.

1. Remove *Navigation Property* `Sheet` from `SheetDetail`
2. Wrap your objects in *ViewModel* classes with *Navigation Property* `Sheet` omitted
3. Create a metadata class with `JsonIgnoreAttribute` and then attach it to your entity with partial class and `MetadataTypeAttribute`

Here you can find sample for third solution (sample makes some assumptions as I don't know your exact data types):

```
public class SheetDetailSerializationMetadata
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Sheet Sheet { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(SheetDetailSerializationMetadata))]
public partial class SheetDetail
{ 
}
```

Comment: +1, looks like circular object reference to me too. Here is a good link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Answer (score 0):

As @danludwig comment, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization gives all answers about my problem.

Add below code in **Global.asax** solves the problem.

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```