# control [JsonIgnore] in ASP.NET Web API during runtime

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, json.net

As we know, ASP.NET web api (ApiController) gives JSON response automatically through NewtonSoft.JSON.

My three-level **1:MANY:1** EF data model is queried in several ways and it works fine with applying [JsonIgnore] attribute to some virtual properties in order to eliminate reference circulation issue.
(I use third solution in [this(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060609/why-my-super-simple-asp-net-web-api-mvc4entity-framework-5-doesnt-work) answer)

but my problem is, I sometimes need to use json-ignored properties to query with model.

Is there any method to control **[JsonIgnore]** attribute during runtime?
Or, is there any method to switch on-and-off property to be ignored in NewtonSoft.JSON during runtime?

Comment: You solved this problem?

Comment: @oakio // No, I didn't solve it. but I concluded that it is not possible because such a attribute is pre-compiler feature in general.

Comment: I am found solution, see 'Conditional Property Serialization' http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Comment: @oakio // wow! amazing gem you found! :) thanks very much. it finally solved!

Comment: @oakio // if you write your contents as an answer, I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know two way to solve this problem:

1. You may add additional boolean property (with specific name) into your model. This is solution is very simple, but requires changes to your model.
2. You may write own `IContractResolver`. This method is more complex, but more flexible.

Both solutions described here: 'Conditional Property Serialization' http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm