# Navigation property in reverse direction in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, entity-framework-5

I created EF models using existing database as below link. a basic master-detail model, db names are Sheet and SheetDetail.

[Why my super simple ASP.NET Web API (mvc4)+Entity Framework 5 doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060609/why-my-super-simple-asp-net-web-api-mvc4entity-framework-5-doesnt-work)

The previous answer solved the recursive navigation property issue, but my new question is
**How can I make a query in reverse direction?**

My previous query was:

```
var result = db.Sheet.Include("SheetDetails").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

My new query was has to be:

```
var result = db.SheetDetail.Include("Sheet").FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
```

But as you imagine, it cannot make it.
I added another Navigation property but no luck.

How can I achieve the above query?
**Note that the json.NET causes an error during serialization.**

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @YeahStu // Thanks for your attention. The Json.NET recursive reference error was received. I agree with the error causes, because it actually makes a circular loop. but I hardly step forward how to achieve. Do I need to make another edmx file?

Comment: Are you still using the JsonIgnore attribute from the previous answer? If so, I fail to see how there is still a circular loop.

Comment: @YeahStu // oh, something mixed up. If I add additional Navigation property from SheetDetail to Sheet (reverse direction than previous one), the circular loop happened. But, without that, how can I make Include("Sheet") in my new query?

Comment: just disable recursive reference errors:
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});`