# Entity Framework vs 2010 Can I do the following:

Tags: entity-framework

I need to migrate data from many xmls to a sql server db and and it has to be done in a transactions.
I thought about EF and dbContext as it's a UOW in it's own right.

My question is
Can you do Database First at run time?

What I want to do is Read all tables from db store in class/dataset and map the db.column to equivalent in xml file and commit.

This has to work in such a way that if a table is added or column added it will work without any code changes as it is driven by db.

The problem I face is that with Db generated from model if a new column is required somebody later on  "unfamiliar with EF" as to add the column "manual job".

I can do what I want with raw ado.net by reading db schema and mapping to a dataset but wondering if I could do it using EF.

Hope all clear

any suggestions

Comment: Though I post an answer, maybe I'm not fully understand your question. Could you tell me about "at run time" more specific? As you know, refreshed EF requires `ALTER` database whenver the schema needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) which allows you to create Code-First file from Database of yours as you start like Code-First.

Or, you can use Database-first approach also. It's not that hard.

If you try to use database-first approach, please read my trial-and-error experience: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060609/why-my-super-simple-asp-net-web-api-mvc4entity-framework-5-doesnt-work), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046614/select-error-on-ef-using-existing-master-detail-database)

Comment: @Younjae thanks for your reply.Database first approach is all before hand .Correct? that will not solve my problem. Not sure I have the time to learn the other stuff unless there is a tutorial somewhere that shows how to generate classes at runtime based on the db schema

Comment: For me, generated `.tt` files from EF database-first approach always creates new schema-reflected classes whenever you refresh the edmx. Is this what you want?

Comment: that sounds good to me.Are you saying that when a new column is added to a database for example,all somebody has to do is right click the "tt" file and you will have a new set of classes generated for you? Any tutorials that I can quickly try with 2 tables. Do I need to download power tools?With vs 2010 the latest EF version is 4.4 is this good

Comment: Yes, just open edmx file and right-click `Update Model from Database` then it creates all classes from `.tt` template files. If it does not create classes after communicating from SQL server, please click `Run custom tool` in Solution explorer>your_db.edmx file. You doesn't need to install power tool if you only want to use database-first approach, so do I :)

Comment: ok that sounds good,so all there is left to do when a column is added is modify the "dto" that maps to the EF model or is there a way to generate that too, One thing that was not clear ,I dont need power tool to do this ,EF does it on it;s own accord

Comment: Yes. you can edit schema, and fetch it to edmx, and the `Update Model from Database` command can make classes at **any time**. And, you doesn't need power tool, only EF+VS can do it.